# Setting future dates in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Update for clarity:  I have a starting date of Wed or Sat for one lottery ticket, and Tue or Fri for another.  Given the starting date, I need an indefinite number of future drawing dates for the tickets, alternating between the given days for the respective tickets.  The starting dates have already been validated to land on these days of the week for their games.

I want to check that the Powerball drawings are scheduled consecutively on the proper dates of Wed or Sat:

```
# Increment zero is the first subsequent drawing
    if increment.zero?
      if starting_date.saturday? or starting_date.friday?
        starting_date + 4.days
      else
        starting_date + 3.days
      end
    elsif increment == 1
      starting_date + 1.week
    else
      if starting_date.saturday? or starting_date.friday?
        starting_date + (increment / 2.0).ceil.weeks + 4.days
      else
        starting_date + (increment / 2.0).ceil.weeks + 3.days
      end
    end
```

Some results I'm getting...

```
t.lines[0].draw_date  #=> Wed, 09 Mar 2016 
t.lines[1].draw_date  #=> Sat, 12 Mar 2016 
t.lines[2].draw_date  #=> Wed, 16 Mar 2016 
t.lines[3].draw_date  #=> Sat, 19 Mar 2016 
t.lines[4].draw_date  #=> Sat, 26 Mar 2016 
t.lines[5].draw_date  #=> Sat, 26 Mar 2016 
t.lines[6].draw_date  #=> Sat, 02 Apr 2016 
t.lines[7].draw_date  #=> Sat, 02 Apr 2016
```

It seems like there should be a simple solution.

Comment: What is `t.lines`? What is `draw_date`? And what are your expected results?

Comment: each line should be the next Wed or Sat from the previous date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

```
  if increment.even?
    if starting_date.saturday? or starting_date.friday?
      starting_date + (increment / 2).weeks + 4.days
    else
      starting_date + (increment / 2).weeks + 3.days
    end
  elsif increment.odd?
    if starting_date.saturday? or starting_date.friday?
      starting_date + (increment / 2.0).ceil.weeks
    else
      starting_date + (increment / 2.0).ceil.weeks
    end
  end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here, this code is needlessly complicated!

Comment: I need to get the draw date for a bunch of consecutive lottery tickets, given an index.  With the start date and the index, and the day of the week of the start date, I can calculate the subsequent draw date for each index. The end result is `Wed > Sat > Wed > Sat etc., for powerball, and Fri > Tue > Fri > Tue` for megamillions. It works fine.

Comment: By index you mean an offset?

Answer (score 0):

```
loop do
  break d if d.wednesday? || d.saturday?
  d += 1.day
end
```